# Android platform version by country

Tags: android, android-api-levels

Is there any way to get the platform versions like in here [Android Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/dashboards/index.html) but regarding each country?

I'm going to start a project which only targets Germany and I am interested in knowing which is the lowest API version for that country, as in the dashboard you get a global value.

Comment: did you find any tool? I would be also interested